# Best performing JavaScript MVC framework for mobile development

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

When I say mobile dev I mean both in the browser, and compiled to PhoneGap.

I'm trying to compare performance numbers JS MVC frameworks. I've googled for this, but when you say Mobile, JS, and framework all you get are links to Sencha, jQuery Mobile, Titanium, etc.

I'm specifically referring to MVC frameworks such as:

```
Ember
Backbone
Spine
Knockout
JavaScript MVC
Batman
Blossom
etc.
```

I'd love to see links which contain performance metrics for each of these in mobile browsers, as well as PhoneGap.

Comment: I've been looking into sencha touch for the same purpose and it seems to provide the whole MVC + UI framework. I'm playing around with it but it seems as a good option to keep in mind. I've also checked into backbone.js and found some people doing some tweaking for it to work with jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 5):

Also worth a look is [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org). It's a complete Javascript framework, created by some Google employees, with a growing community. It's really fun to work with!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to have a look at this tutorial [Using Backbone.js with jQuery Mobile](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/).
It explains how to override JQM routing system to handle it with the one provided by Backbone.js (that is much better).
Yesterday I've found even this analysis [10 reasons why I switched to Spine.js](http://destroytoday.com/blog/reasons-for-spinejs/) that give some point of view about the differences between Spine.js and Backbone.js.
Then, if you like metrics, you can have a look at this comparison between the different [JS Template Engines Performance](http://jsperf.com/js-template-engines-performance/7)
I understand the fear in using JQuery Mobile, since the performances are not good on all devices, but as far as I know, it's the only one working with all mobile platforms (not just on webkit) and the only one that graceful degrades on unsupported browsers.
In conclusion, I don't think there's a right solution among all, it depends on what you are trying to achieve, what is your target, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried them all, but I have done some research on the topic, and have ended up using to **[Backbone JS](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)**. I am very pleased with it's simplicity and power so far. I very much like being able to read through the source code (only 6kb minified!) and understand what its saying.

I got started on Backbone-powered mobile-optimized apps with [a tutorial from Trigger.io](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.2/best_practice/example_project.html#using-backbone-js) (a maker of a PhoneGap-like native app wrapper). I've adapted it to my own purposes, and made some important modifications such as using CSS transitions instead of (slow) javascript animations.

I created a extendable Backbone.View.MobileView object that makes building mobile optimized applications quick and easy. I've been meaning to post it to gist, but it still needs quite a bit of clean up. If you want a rough version as a reference, I would be happy to share.

Just one other note - I would **avoid jQuery Mobile** at all costs. Besides the huge overhead of the combined jQuery and jQuery Mobile frameworks, you will find your code and styles being overwritten at every turn. And from what I've found passing data back-and-forth to the server with AJAX between pages is a real pain.

Mobile-optimized apps are the wild-wild-west of web development, especially when it comes to integrating with PhoneGap-like services. Please share what you've learned with the rest of us!

**Good luck!**

Comment: "I would avoid jQuery Mobile at all costs" Wouldn't this make you have to develop the whole mobile UI by yourself? For every device screen size? Seems like a lot of work already done by jQuery Mobile.

Comment: I don't agree with the statement "avoid using jQuery Mobile at all costs". It's not the solution for every situation, but it IS a perfect solution for SOME situations. It handles everything for you: ui, routing, rendering, and more.

Comment: Brock Whitten, the co-creator of PhoneGap has outlined that jQuery Mobile is one of the easiest and biggest mistakes you can make when creating a mobile application in HTML5.

http://sintaxi.com/you-half-assed-it

Comment: Hi, It will help if you share your modified version of BackBone, Thanks

Comment: The tutorial link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

I think spine.js & knockout.js is pretty good

however both of them are slightly complex

let me know which one you used